# VS Code Autocomplete python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm pretty new to python and would like to have autocompletion using vs code inside my project.
For external modules it works fine but I dont get autocompletion for my own files/modules.

For example, I have a main.py file inside my src folder and a roboter.py next to it.
I import a Roboter class via `from roboter import Roboter` and it runs fine but I dont get any autocompletion on it.

Also, I'm using no virtual env but have all other packages global on which I do get autocompletion.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, installing a 64 bit version of python instead of a 32 bit version did the job.